# Obtaining an access_token with ADAL

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-teams

I'm developing a Sharepoint Web Part that I want to use in Teams. I would like to obtain an access_token from the user logged in Teams using Adal library, without need to relogin.

I had tried something like this, but not works.

```
        //ADAL.js configuration
        let config = {
            clientId: "XXXXXXXXXXX",
            popUp: true
            extraQueryParameters: "scope=openid+profile&login_hint=" + this.context.sdks.microsoftTeams.context.loginHint
        };

        let authContext = new AuthenticationContext(config);

        authContext.login();

        // See if there's a cached user and it matches the expected user
        let user = authContext.getCachedUser();
        if (user) {
            if (user.userName !== this.context.sdks.microsoftTeams.context.loginHint) {
                // User doesn't match, clear the cache
                authContext.clearCache();
            }
        }

        // Get the id token (which is the access token for resource = clientId)
        let token = authContext.getCachedToken(config.clientId);
        if (token) {
            console.log(token);
        } else {
            // No token, or token is expired

            authContext._renewIdToken((err, idToken) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Renewal failed: " + err);
                    // Failed to get the token silently; show the login button
                } else {
                    console.log(idToken);
                }
            });
        }
```

Have somebody any idea?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I have found a solution that works in Sharepoint and Teams at the same time:

```
        let loginName = this.context.pageContext.user.loginName;
        let source = Sources.sharepoint;

        // Obtaining loginName from Teams context
        if (this.context.sdks.microsoftTeams) {
            loginName = this.context.sdks.microsoftTeams.context.loginHint;
            source = Sources.teams;
        }


        // Obtaining token provider
        let tp = await this.context.aadTokenProviderFactory.getTokenProvider();
        let config = tp["_defaultConfiguration"];
        let aadInstanceUrl = config.aadInstanceUrl[length - 1] === "/" ? config.aadInstanceUrl : config.aadInstanceUrl + "/";

        // Config context
        let ctx = new AuthenticationContext({
            tenant: tenantId,
            clientId: clientId,
            instance: aadInstanceUrl,
            redirectUri: config.redirectUri,
            extraQueryParameter: "login_hint=" + encodeURIComponent(loginName),
            loadFrameTimeout: 60000
        });

        // Check user
        let cu = ctx.getCachedUser();
        console.log("USER", cu, loginName, ctx);
        if (cu && cu.userName.toLowerCase() !== loginName.toLowerCase()) {
            console.log("Clean user cache");
            ctx.clearCache();
        }

        // Obtaining token using Adal library
        let token = this.acquireToken(ctx, clientId);

        // Render application
        token.then((result) => {
            console.log("iframe token: "+result); // "Stuff worked!"
        }, (err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
```

---

```
private acquireToken(ctx: AuthenticationContext, resource: string){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            ctx.acquireToken(resource, (message, token) =>{
                if(!token){
                    console.log("acquireToken: Error obtaining token: "+message);
                    reject(token);
                }else{
                    console.log("acquireToken: Token: "+message);
                    resolve(token);
                }
            });

        });
    }
```